# Failed to create Context 0x3005

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, installation, android-virtual-device

I have windows 8, Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (JUNO ) for Windows 32 bit, and the updated and installed Android SDK 4.1.2 for windows.

I've unzipped the Android SDK for Windows, opened the SDK manager and installed:

```
Android SDK tool.
Android SDK platform tools
Android 4.1.2 (API 16) - all the folder
All the Extra folder.
```

After that I've opened the AVD manager and created a new AVD with the Google API 16 on with Nexus 7 (I've tried all of them ). When i am trying to run an app, am getting the following error:

*

```
> Failed to create Context 0x3005 emulator: 
> WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
> could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
> could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
> could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
> could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
> could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
```

*

I have tried all answers. Unfortunately, nothing works for me. Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: have you installed adt plugin for eclipse?

Comment: I confirm the problem. Here is the related [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=47829). A solution is wanted.

Comment: And one more related [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41032) is found. I'm using the latest SDK, platform and Eclipse plugins, so the bug is not fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to AVD manager, Select created AVD & then Edit. Check the box Use Host GPU.. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install JDK that supports the Android SDK. JRE alone is not sufficient!
   It worked for me. After installing JDK, close Eclipse and open the project again.
2. If this still does not work, check the path variable for Java